# Timestamp fields showing Timezone string in data in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery having columns with `timestamp` type. After loading the data I can see these fields containing `timezone` information as well which is not required.

for example: `2016-03-31 19:23:07 UTC`

What I actually want : `2016-03-31 19:23:07`

Is there any way by which I can ask Bigquery to store and show the data in my desired format only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep the `TIMESTAMP`column type, and since it's UTC based it's the standard how dates should be stored. If you do this otherwise, you may be doing wrong and you will run into problems as your application matures.

If you want to store date in a format you want, you need to make it an arbitrary `string`, but this is not advised.